# break links into chunks with a sliding window

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, iterator, sliding-window

So, i'm trying to break a list up into chunks of 4 but with a caveat. The caveat is that I want the list to take the last 2 elements of the previous chunk and concatenate it with the next 2 elements to make the following output:

For example:

```
Input: text=['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight']
Output: ['one two three four','three four five six', 'five six seven eight']
```

Right now, I have this:

```
from itertools import islice

text=['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight']

def window(seq, n=2):
    "Returns a sliding window (of width n) over data from the iterable"
    "   s -> (s0,s1,...s[n-1]), (s1,s2,...,sn), ...                   "
    it = iter(seq)
    result = tuple(islice(it, n))
    if len(result) == n:
        yield result
    for elem in it:
        result = result[1:] + (elem,)
        yield result

processed = [' '.join(i) for i in window(text,4)]
print(processed)
Output:
['one two three four', 'two three four five', 'three four five six', 'four five six seven', 'five six seven eight']
```

Again, my ideal output would be:

`['one two three four','three four five six', 'five six seven eight']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
data = 'i ii iii iv v vi vii viii'.split()

print([' '.join(data[i-2:i+2]) for i in range(2, len(data), 2)])
```

Comment: Why not use a step of 2 for the `range`, then you can avoid `[::2]` on the result...

Comment: This won't hold if you add one more item to the list as the last chunk will be only 3 items.

Comment: I'm not sure I would use "of course" in regard to my python knowledge... still very much a newbie...

Comment: @MarsilinouZaky it is not clear to me what 4-chunking a list with a cardinality that is not divisible by 4 should do. Given the spec, this is at least one sensible solution :-)